# how to change the datatype of numpy.random.rand array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm learning Numpy module from scratch going through the official Numpy documentation. 
Now my goal is to create a random (3, 3) array.

```
>>> np.random.rand(3,3)
```

However the output I recieved is a bunch of random float values.

```
array([[ 0.33519419,  0.53502883,  0.35485002],
   [ 0.73419236,  0.85315716,  0.64135169],
   [ 0.51732791,  0.27411508,  0.32482598]])
```

I wonder how can I do the same with `int`
Referring the Official documentation of Numpy for the `numpy.random.rand` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand) I don't find a clue on converting or specifying the data type from float values to integer.
How can I achieve random values in `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate random `int`, use [np.random.randint()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html).

If you want to convert `float` to `int`, use `np.int32(something)`.

Comment: Oh Thanks. by the way whats the purpose of `numpy.random.rand()` function? Is it only to display the float value?

Comment: Generate a random float between 0, 1. See documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html

Comment: Thanks I got it now :-)

Comment: The results most are "0" and "1", so how to convert like 0.01231341, 0.2341235. 0.234246524... to 1231341, 2341235, 234246524